# Prisma.Schema will not Update

Tags: prisma

I am having the dumbest issue ever with my schema file. It has nothing to do with the Models or any properties or actual information, but rather the file is just refusing to save, or update the saved changes.
The prisma.schema file worked perfectly and we had to make a couple of minor changes, literally just changing the names of some of the models' values. For some reason, this made my file unable to read the contents of my `.env` file... fine, I only needed it for the URL anyway. This being said I then changed the following code from this...

```
datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url = env("DATABASE_URL")
}
```

to this...

```
datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url = "postgresql://nick:Abc!123@localhost:5432/tom?schema=public"
}
```

But whenever I run any command that will involve the schema file in some way (`node server.js`, `npx prisma migrate dev` etc) it will give me the following error...

```
PrismaClientInitializationError: error: Environment variable not found: DATABASE_URL.
  -->  schema.prisma:8
   | 
 7 |   provider = "postgresql"
 8 |   url = env("DATABASE_URL")
   |
```

which is clearly just not what I have in my code anymore. I've never seen anything like this, I've closed vscode, I've restarted my machine, any ideas?

Comment: I can't seem to replicate the problem. I had a few questions. Are you sure it's not something silly like you're in the wrong folder when executing commands or something? Any way you can help to reproduce the problem? What version of Prisma and what OS are you on btw? Also, does @Danila's answer help?

Comment: I actually just kind of gave up on it, I tried to replicate it in another new project and of course nothing happened and it worked fine. I ended up git stashing and just totally rebuilding it from the ground up, not sure what happened there, must have been something with my machine because that's a very weird error

Comment: Ah alright, sounds good!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to run `prisma generate` command after you make any changes to the `schema.prisma` file.